# Windows Serv 2008 R2 - IIS7 redirect ip adress to name

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7

I am hosting a local site with Windows Server 2008 R2 and i really don't know how client can access to the site with a name "ex: test.com" instead of ip adress.

I have search with DNS but i don't understand how can i use it with my site.
I am tried it => [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1166153.aspx) but it's doesn't work and i don't know why... i am really confused i can't explained the problem.

Any help is welcome ...

Comment: Do you have control of your local DNS servers?

Comment: Yes i can manage DNS on site's server.

Comment: And so, what name do you want the end-users to access your site using?

Comment: I want end-users accessing my site with : "intranet.com", What are the steps please?

Comment: [A Beginners Guide to DNS](http://www.d2digital.co.uk/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-dns-domain-name-system.aspx) - you need to read this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have that domain on your DNS server, simply add an A record with no name and the public IP address of the server that you want your customers to connect to.

You would then need to set a binding in IIS with the hostname that you want, which matches the DNS record you just created.